# Help with a limit of two variables

Tags: calculus

i can't seem to find this limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{(5\cos y)(\sin y-x)}{4\left | x-\sin y \right |^{3/4}}$$
Wolfram says it doesn't exist but i don't understand why,can someone help me?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: $\cos(y) $ goes to 1.after simplification, it gives zero.

Comment: So the limit is 0?Why is wolfram saying that it doesn't exist?

Comment: For clarity the expression should be improved with a few more parentheses.

Comment: It depends on how you entered the function at Wolfram. As it stands your notation is not clear. What did you put in at W?

Comment: @zhw My input at wolfram is lim_({x, y}->{0, 0})(5 cos(y) (sin(y) - x))/(4 abs(x - sin(y))^(3/4)) .I am new to the forum,can you suggest a fix for the parentheses?i will accept it.Sorry.

Comment: I can't get anything out of Wolfram, and I don't know why anyone goes there  to do mathematics. I fixed the parentheses. The limit is $0,$ as indicated in some of the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I used it to double check my solution and it caused more confusion if anything.The graph "looks fine" at (0,0) according to wolfram,but also the limit doesn't exist?Duh,weird,i will let 0 as my final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is why Wolfram is saying that the limit doesn't exist. Wolfram tells you this when you input your query

> lim_({x, y}->{0, 0})(5 cos(y) (sin(y) - x))/(4 abs(x - sin(y))^(3/4))

It says "Value may depend on x,y path in complex space". Wolfram thinks that x and y are complex variables not real numbers

Comment: Thanks a lot!Cleared the confusion in my head,didn't see the last part.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\pm 5}{4}|\sin(y)-x|^{\frac{1}{4}}\cos(y)$$

and the limit is zero.

Comment: Hi again,i agree witht his and this is how i originally solved it but wolfram said that the limit doesn't exist so i am not sure :[ .

Comment: That cannot be the function as it is lacking the $\;\cos y\;$ part...that this part tends to $\;1\;$ doesn't mean it disappears.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Apparently you didn't read *all* my comment...

Comment: @DonAntonio Do you agree that the limit is 0?I know the question seems too easy but wolfram doesn't agree and i am a bit worried.Thanks all for the answers,you are all wonderful people :) .

Answer (score 0):

How $|\frac{5}{4} \frac{\cos y(\sin y - x)}{|x- \sin y |^{3/4}}| \leq \frac{5}{4} |\frac{(\sin y - x)}{|x- \sin y |^{3/4}}| = \frac{5}{4} |x- \sin y |^{1/4} \to 0$
as $(x,y) \to 0$ and therefore  $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0}\frac{5}{4} \frac{\cos y(\sin y - x)}{|x- \sin y |^{3/4}}| = 0$. Note that in first inlequality, we use that $|\cos y| \leq 1$.

Comment: Similarly,if $x>=siny$ then the absolute value is removed and i get 0,for $x<=siny$ i get the same result,however wolfram says that the limit doesn't exist so i am not really sure :S